# How do i retrieve values (Message) and (Code) from the reply of twitter api?

Tags: php, oauth, twitter-oauth

I am using codebird to post update using php, that i am doing successfully until when i get this message as reply by oauth for failure

```
object(stdClass)[2]
  public 'errors' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[3]
          public 'code' => int 187
          public 'message' => string 'Status is a duplicate.' (length=22)
  public 'httpstatus' => int 403
  public 'rate' => null
```

I am able to retrieve rate successfully using the following code

```
$httpstatus = $reply->httpstatus;
```

But i am unable to retrieve the rest especially the code and message, and when i try the above code it returns nothing or empty string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
foreach($reply->errors AS $error){
 echo 'error code:'. $error->code;
 echo 'error message:'. $error->message;
}
```

As you can see, errors property is an array, so you must itarate

Comment: So it a multidimensional array?

Comment: Not exactly, $reply is object, error property is one dimension array `array('key' => 'object')` 

If my answare is working for you, please accept it ;)

Comment: i understand now, btw it worked after after some modification, i requested for a real array instead of an object, it was easy dealing with an array when i was ur code up there